# forcing noVNC background & removing auto-set title

Tags: javascript, html, kvm

I've got noVNC working earlier today but have ran into 2 issues with it, hours of Google have avail to nothing.

1. noVNC sets a weird background with a load of white area which looks like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFS7j.png, I looked up the noVNC css files but couldn't find much to fix this up or set a solid-wallpaper color.
2. noVNC re-sets the  tag with noVNC automatically once the page finishes loading, I assume to do with Javascript but I looked through files as well and couldn't find it, https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5B9x.png

Any help with these 2 topics would be helpful.

Thanks & Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for issue #1 in base.css, editing out the line

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 800px 600px;
```

fixes this up.

Still looking for a fix to #2